# What is the best way to add a different billing address in a e-commerce website?

Tags: forms, e-commerce, addresses, billing, shipping

I'm a UX designer, actually working on a e-commerce website template.

Here are my doubts :

When users want to buy a product, the moment they are doing the address form, if they want to receive the bill to another address (different than the shipping address), should we put :

- A checkbox, checked by default on "Same address for billing", and when they uncheck it, users can add the billing address.
- An empty checkbox "Add another address for billing", so users check it to add the billing address
- A call to action button "Add a different billing address" ?

Wording is absolutely not done, as you read, but it just to give you an idea of my problematic.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Well, it could depend on context, for example, digital goods vs physical good delivery. But here are two threads, that have similar discussions - should be helpful: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76345/same-as-billing-address-checkbox-ticked-or-unticked-by-default & http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45941/same-as-shipping-address-or-different-from-shipping-address

I would personally stick with "Add different address for billing". Reason being, its more logical to select an option and do some following action, rather than un-check and perform the same. Suits the metal model better.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with the "Add a different billing address" option. Following from major e-commerce platforms like Amazon and Shopify, their option is consistent, regardless of if the item(s) being purchased is digital or physical, in assuming that most of the time the user is going to have the same billing address as their shipping address, reducing the click depth in the checkout process.

On integrating this, I would suggest splitting up the two address in different stages of the checkout process, clearly defining the shipping address to the item(s) they are purchasing, and the billing address to their payment, just to reinforce their meaning, and this will also reduce the screen clutter when the user is trying to enter a different address, as you would need to display a duplicate form with the same fields as the shipping address.

Here is an example integration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds great!  Thanks! I like the idea to repeat the address in the billing section because user can see if he made any mistake in the form before. Thank you Cody!